# Can we proof that this specific function is decreasing and concave in $x$ when $0 \le x \le 0.5d$?

Tags: calculus, functions

I want to apply an algorithm that uses marginal analysis but in order to make sure it can be done, I want to rigorously proof the following function is decreasing and concave in $x$. I checked it extensively but that was only numerically.

This is the function I'm looking at

$$g(x) = pT\left(\frac{qx}{ds}\right)$$,

where $p, q, d, s$ $\in \mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ and are all constants. The function $T(z)$ is the following:

$$T(z) = 4.85-0.3924z^{1.3}-5.359z^{0.135}.$$

We can see that $g(x)$ is decreasing in $x$, but can we also prove that $g(x)$ is concave  when $0 \le x \le 0.5d$ ?

Comment: We can't see $g(x)$ is decreasing in $x$ without the specific choice of constants. For example, $p=-1,q=1,d=1,s=1,x=0.5$ gives $g'(0.5)=1.73202$ so that $g$ is increasing

Comment: Oops, indeed. Let me edit that!

Comment: Why not plot the function and drivatives with sliders for constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $z=\frac{x}{d}$ so that $0 \leq z \leq 0.5$. Now $g(x)=pT\left(\frac{qx}{ds}\right) = h(z) = pT\left(\frac{qz}{s}\right)$. Now differentiate with respect to $z$ to get:
$$\frac{d}{dz}h=-\frac{p \left(0.51012 \left(\frac{q z}{s}\right)^{1.3}+0.723465 \left(\frac{q z}{s}\right)^{0.135}\right)}{z}$$
Easy to see this is always negative so long as $z>0$. Next, take the second derivative
$$\frac{d^2}{dz^2}h=\frac{p \left(0.625797\left(\frac{q z}{s}\right)^{0.135}-0.153036\left(\frac{q z}{s}\right)^{1.3}\right)}{z^2}$$
Now for this to be positive, we need:
$$0.625797\left(\frac{q z}{s}\right)^{0.135}-0.153036\left(\frac{q z}{s}\right)^{1.3}>0$$
However this simplifies to
$$\left(\frac{q z}{s}\right)^{1.165} < 4.089214303\implies \left(\frac{q z}{s}\right)\in \left( 0,  3.349753881\right)$$
So the function isn't concave everywhere (choosing $z=0.5,p=1,q=6,s=1$ gives a point where the function is convex).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So we do can say that as long $g(x)$ is nonnegative, the function is decreasing concave ?

Comment: @Steven, Once again, I'd have to say it really depends on the choice of constants. If you look at the graph provided by Shiv, we see that the function is convex wherever it is nonnegative, even though the constants satisfy the nonnegativity constraints.

Comment: but no matter how you set the constants, there is no way that the second derivative can be negative when the constants give a positive result to $g(x)$ ?

Comment: Hmm yeah okay you're right

Comment: yes? I’m not trying to be contrary so I’f I’m wrong, I’m wrong. It’s hard for me to tell if this was said with sarcasm, therefore I ask to verify :)

Comment: No no I wasn't being sarcastic. You are actually correct

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an experimental problem with decimal values so graphing the function instead of analysing the double derivative. Setting all constants equal to $1$. We see that the function $g(x)$ is not concave when $0 \leq x \leq 0.5\times 1 \leq 0.5$.

[image: Graph of T(x)]

Used [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/) for Graphing.